# request an endorsement - recommendation?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

If a person is considering buying something and writing to a company to ask for a recommendation of a product or service, can we say he or she is requesting an endorsement?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: this is the same as the question you asked yesterday IMO. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152988/meaning-of-endorse/152991#152991

Comment: I am trying to provide a context for the usage to see if it fits.

Comment: @Apollyon And there's nothing wrong with asking for context, but you should do it on your original question, not open a new one.

Comment: Agreed with Neil, especially seeing as your previous question still remains open and, again, in my opinion the teachings in your previous question will answer this question... Public endorsement vs. support. Ask yourself is this company publicly endorsing the product or service or are they just simply saying 'try this' if it's the former (usually linked to sponsorships in the corporate world) its an endorsement of course, if it's the latter then it is likely just a recommendation I.e., support, I.e., not an endorsement.